# Show ${f_n(x)}_ {n=1, \cdots, \infty}$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If $f_n(x) = \dfrac{x}{1+nx}$, show that ${f_n(x)}_{n=1, \cdots, \infty}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $(0,1)$.

Here is what I have so far:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Pick any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall \epsilon >0$ let $N> 1/\epsilon$ (such an $N$ exists by the Archimedean property).

Then $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |\dfrac{x}{1+nx} - 0| \ \ \forall n \geq N$.

$|\dfrac{x}{1+nx} | \leq 1/n ≤ \epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your reasoning is not very organized. So its hard to follow what you were thinking about as you worked through this. I've give some hints in my post...

Comment: $(f_n(x))$ is a sequence of numbers, it doesn't make sense to speak of uniform convergence. You probably want to show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to 0